# web.config connection string not set Context?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

i am using asp.net mvc and using entity framework in a class library.

my entity context:

```
public class AmarContext : DbContext
{
    public AmarContext()
        : base("AmarGiriEntities")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<AmarTable> Amars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GuidDetailsTable> GuidDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GuidIDTable> GuidIDs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IPsTable> IPs { get; set; }
}
```

my Web.config Connectionstring:

```
    <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AmarGiriEntities" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=FrameSoftAmar;User ID=username;Password=pass;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
   ...
```

but if i check connection string return me this:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|AmarGiriEntities.mdf;Initial Catalog=AmarGiriEntities;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

why?
if i test my class library in a console application and set connection string in app.config its works.but from asp.net mvc not working.

Comment: Try adding to provider name : 
 <add name="AmarGiriEntities" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=False;Initial Catalog=FrameSoftAmar;User ID=username;Password=pass;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient />

Comment: thank you for replay.. i'm added provider name not working...

Comment: Some applications provide a default connection string.Due to this reason the application's configuration manager has multiple connection strings defined. If you are experiencing this issue you can add `<clear/>` on top to the `<connectionStrings>` section.

Comment: my web.config file have only one <connectionStrings>

Comment: Try searching AmarGiriEntities.mdf in complete solution. If that connection string present in your solution. Then atleast you will be able to locate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you tried add `<clear/>` tag like Stefan comment? It should solve.

Check this section too:

`<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0...." MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>`

If not solve, check where is located your Web.Config file. Remember that there is a precedence convention over this file.

See: [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685(v=vs.140).aspx)